# How to configure SIBus to invoke a client web service

Tags: web-services, websphere, messaging

I'm new to WAS and trying to understand some basic concepts. I'm looking into using WAS and I read about the default messaging provider with SIBus. Can the SIBus messaging engine be used/configured to send messages(SOAP) to a client WS? I hope this question makes sense. thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

You can send SOAP messages using "**SOAP over JMS**", which in turn uses the Websphere **SIBus** infrastructure. You can read more [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/tjw_services.html).

However I would recommend reading first the [Bus-enabled web services FAQ](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/cjw_faq.html) before starting implement this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We are going to use SOAP over HTTP...so I guess that is gonna use the Outbound Services bus type rather than SIB. Is that correct? Another newbie question is I haven't had any luck with figuring out how to call the Outbound Service. Does this service work off a queue or is it called directly from code? big thanks!

Comment: If you will use SOAP over HTTP you definitely do not need the SIBus nor setting up the Outbound Service. You must just find the WSDL of the Web Service and build the Web Service client using JAX-WS. More on this here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/tjw_services.html